# How to fit TensorFlow Serving Client API in a Python lambda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, aws-lambda, data-science, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to build a Python Lambda to send images to TensorFlow Serving for inferences.  I have at least two dependencies: CV2 and tensorflow_serving.apis.  I've run multiple tutorials showing it's possible to run tensorflow in a lambda, but they provide the package to install and don't explain how they got it to fit in the limit of less than 256MB unzipped.

- [How to Deploy ... Lambda and TensorFlow](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-deep-learning-models-with-aws-lambda-and-tensorflow/)
- [Using TensorFlow and the Serverless Framework...](https://serverless.com/blog/using-tensorflow-serverless-framework-deep-learning-image-recognition/)

I've tried following the [official instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-dependencies) for packaging but just this downloads 475MB of dependencies:

```
$ python -m pip install tensorflow-serving-api --target .
Collecting tensorflow-serving-api
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/69/1e724c0d98f12b12f9ad583a3df7750e14ec5f06069aa4be8d75a2ab9bb8/tensorflow_serving_api-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
...
$ du -hs .
475M    .
```

I see that others have fought this dragon and won ([1](https://medium.com/@mojodna/slimming-down-lambda-deployment-zips-b3f6083a1dff)) ([2](https://blog.waya.ai/deploy-deep-machine-learning-in-production-the-pythonic-way-a17105f1540e)) by doing contortions to rip out all unused libraries from all dependencies or compile from scratch.  But such extremes strike me as complicated and hopefully outdated in a world where data science and lambdas are almost mainstream.  Is it true that so few people are using TensorFlow Serving with Python that I'll have to jump through such hoops to get one working as a Lambda?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Here's another possible option for some, but it doesn't seem like it will work for me because I need my /tmp space for the images I'm resizing before sending to TF Serving.  https://blog.zappa.io/posts/slim-handler

Comment: Here's another possible option for some, but it's using tensorflow 1.8 rather than the latest stable version, tensorflow 1.12.  Maybe 1.8 is just smaller? https://github.com/antonpaquin/Tensorflow-Lambda-Layer

Comment: Here's someone who fought this dragon narrowly with numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10920

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to not actually have tensorflow on the client side, as it uses a ton of space but isn't really needed for inference. Unfortunately the `tensorflow-serving-api` requires the entire `tensorflow` package, which by itself is too big to fit into a lambda.

What you can do instead is build your own client instead of using that package. This involves using the `grpcio-tools` package for the protobuf communication, and the various `.proto` files from tensorflow and tensorflow serving.

Specifically you'll want to package up these files-

```
tensorflow/serving/  
  tensorflow_serving/apis/model.proto
  tensorflow_serving/apis/predict.proto
  tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_service.proto
tensorflow/tensorflow/  
  tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.proto
  tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto
  tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto
  tensorflow/core/framework/types.proto
```

From there you can generate the python protobuf files.